# How to bind to action for radio button in install4j

Tags: java, install4j

I'm using install4j in order to create installation wizard.

I have a radio button group that contains 2 different button, in case of selecting the second button i would like to show on the same page some addition fields, while selecting the first one i would like to hide them.

User input, Variable name: test.radio

Radio button labels: radio1;radio2

Is there any possible way to bind to which radio button is selected and perform a "hide & show" operation for some text fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Single radio button" form components instead of the "Radio button group" form component. In the configuration panel of those form components there is a "Coupled form components" tab that allows you to hide or show other form components depending on whether the radio button is selected.

Comment: but then how can i make sure only one of them is selected?

Comment: "Single radio button" form components with the same configured variable name form a radio button group.

Comment: So at the end i have to create only 2 single radio button and have the same variable name in both of them and not use at all the radio button group :)